# Codeingiter Get count faster way

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Which is fast way to get the count of selected records in codeigniter

```
num_rows()
count()
result_array()
```

I have to fetch records more 75,000 or it may increase. Or is there any other way to get faster way to get the count to pass it to pagination

Query is like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE `main_category_id` = 1
```

Comment: `$rowcount = $query->num_rows();` should be fastest followed by `$query->get()->result_array();`

Comment: If the table is `MyISAM`, just do `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, it will be the fastest.

Comment: okay how do  I compare this @Rahul is there any way

Comment: I agree with @MadhurBhaiya, do the counting in SQL... `$this->db->where('main_category_id' = 1', 1);`
`$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count');`
`$_item =  $this->db->get('products')->row()->count;`

Comment: num_rows() takes 20 seconds where as $this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count') with get()->row() it will take just 0.63 seconds